# Elegant way to REDUCE a 2D array into 1D

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given the following 2D array: `var arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

How can get `[1,4,7]` without using `for` loops?

My simplest solution is transposing and returning only the first (0th) row.
There must be a more elegant solution, Perhaps something that I can chain onto an array to make it a one-liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
var arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
var newaArr = arr.map(el => el[0]);
```